# Lost USB BlueTooth Dongle for Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, dongle

I lost my USB bluetooth dongle (from HP) which I used for a wireless keyboard and mouse.
They came together in a set when I bought my last HP computer.

Are the keyboard and mouse useless now? or will any bluetooth dongle allow them to work?
If I can just buy a new one - any recommendations on a replacement (good price, and perhaps works with Windows and Ubuntu out-of-the-box?

Forgive me if this is an easy question. I'm just not that familiar with wireless mice/keyboards.

Comment: My colleague is in the same situation with you ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have thought that any Bluetooth dongle would work. It's the software/driver that reads the Bluetooth data that's important.

Comment: He sohuld be somwhat vary however, of the "class" (or how to they put it, of a device in question). Usually, if I'm not mistaken, mice use "class II" bluetooth devices, but better to check before. I've had some problems of this kind in the past.

Comment: My concern was that these had built-in IDs since they "just work"

Comment: @Tyndall - the mouse and keyboard will have IDs and the software is part of the operating system which is why they "just work". The receiver is the "dumb" part of the system.

Answer (score 2):

I'd ask this question to the manufacturer. You may just ask about the replacement via e-mail as well.

Some time ago the cable from my video card get lost. I wrote to the manufacturer on Taiwan to ask about the pin wiring, to build the new cable myself. I got response "Sure, we can tell, but wouldn't it be easier if we just send you new cable?".

I was surprised again, when after two weeks a package arrived from Taiwan to Europe, and I got brand new cable for free :)

Just try, you risk nothing.